# AS2 Class WORKS locally but not when I put on server UPDATE

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I made a class

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

class com.classes.CollisionDetection {
    static public function checkForCollision(p_clip1:MovieClip,p_clip2:MovieClip,p_alphaTolerance:Number):Rectangle {
        p_clip1.lShots.text = "D";
        // set up default params:
        if (p_alphaTolerance == undefined) { p_alphaTolerance = 255; }

        // get bounds:
        var bounds1:Object = p_clip1.getBounds(_root);
        var bounds2:Object = p_clip2.getBounds(_root);

        // rule out anything that we know can't collide:
        if (((bounds1.xMax < bounds2.xMin) || (bounds2.xMax < bounds1.xMin)) || ((bounds1.yMax < bounds2.yMin) || (bounds2.yMax < bounds1.yMin)) ) {
            return null;
        }

        // determine test area boundaries:
        var bounds:Object = {};
        bounds.xMin = Math.max(bounds1.xMin,bounds2.xMin);
        bounds.xMax = Math.min(bounds1.xMax,bounds2.xMax);
        bounds.yMin = Math.max(bounds1.yMin,bounds2.yMin);
        bounds.yMax = Math.min(bounds1.yMax,bounds2.yMax);

        // set up the image to use:
        var img:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds.xMax-bounds.xMin,bounds.yMax-bounds.yMin,false);

        // draw in the first image:
        var mat:Matrix = p_clip1.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
        mat.tx -= bounds.xMin;
        mat.ty -= bounds.yMin;
        img.draw(p_clip1,mat, new ColorTransform(1,1,1,1,255,-255,-255,p_alphaTolerance));

        // overlay the second image:
        mat = p_clip2.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
        mat.tx -= bounds.xMin;
        mat.ty -= bounds.yMin;
        img.draw(p_clip2,mat, new ColorTransform(1,1,1,1,255,255,255,p_alphaTolerance),"difference");

        // find the intersection:
        var intersection:Rectangle = img.getColorBoundsRect(0xFFFFFFFF,0xFF00FFFF);

        // if there is no intersection, return null:
        if (intersection.width == 0) { return null; }

        // adjust the intersection to account for the bounds:
        intersection.x += bounds.xMin;
        intersection.y += bounds.yMin;

        return intersection;
    }


}
```

and in SWF I write

```
  import com.classes.CollisionDetection;

    function checkCollision(vMc1, vMc2, vT) {
        // check for collisions:
        var collisionRect:Rectangle = CollisionDetection.checkForCollision(vMc1, vMc2, vT);

        if (collisionRect) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

It works locatlly no problem, but wont work online. Any ideas. I played around with classpaths etc...but no luck. :( It appears that its working as the test 'D' gets displayed BUT the HIT isnt working...so not sure what makes the code work locally but not on the internet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely caused by scaling of your Flash in the browser.  All the coordinates used in your shape based collision detection are based on the size of the stage when you first made your movie, so things get messed up when it's scaled.

A solution is to create an an invisible reference rectangle that scales when your movie does.  We just need to add some things to your original code.  I can't take credit for this - Dave Pagurek created this modification of the original by Grant Skinner.

```
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.geom.Point;

checkForCollision = function(p_clip1:MovieClip, p_clip2:MovieClip, p_alphaTolerance:Number):Rectangle  {

    // our magic rectangle:
    if (stageMaskRect) {
        // if this rectangle exists, scale it:
        stageMaskRect._width = Stage.width;
        stageMaskRect._height = Stage.height;
        stageMaskRect._x = 0;
        stageMaskRect._y = 0;
    } else {
        // if not, create it:
        createEmptyMovieClip("stageMaskRect",0);
        stageMaskRect.beginFill(0xFF0000,0);
        stageMaskRect.moveTo(0,0);
        stageMaskRect.lineTo(Stage.width,0);
        stageMaskRect.lineTo(Stage.width,Stage.height);
        stageMaskRect.lineTo(0,Stage.height);
        stageMaskRect.endFill();
        stageMaskRect._x = 0;
        stageMaskRect._y = 0;
    }

    // set up default params:
    if (p_alphaTolerance == undefined) {
        p_alphaTolerance = 255;
    }

    // get bounds:   
    var bounds1:Object = p_clip1.getBounds(_root);
    var bounds2:Object = p_clip2.getBounds(_root);
    // rule out anything that we know can't collide:
    if (((bounds1.xMax<bounds2.xMin) || (bounds2.xMax<bounds1.xMin)) || ((bounds1.yMax<bounds2.yMin) || (bounds2.yMax<bounds1.yMin))) {
        return null;
    }

    // determine test area boundaries:   
    var bounds:Object = {};
    bounds.xMin = Math.max(bounds1.xMin, bounds2.xMin);
    bounds.xMax = Math.min(bounds1.xMax, bounds2.xMax);
    bounds.yMin = Math.max(bounds1.yMin, bounds2.yMin);
    bounds.yMax = Math.min(bounds1.yMax, bounds2.yMax);

    // set up the image to use: Here's our magic rectangle:
    var img:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stageMaskRect._width, stageMaskRect._height, false);

    // draw in the first image:
    var mat:Matrix = p_clip1.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
    mat.tx -= bounds.xMin;
    mat.ty -= bounds.yMin;
    img.draw(p_clip1,mat,new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 255, -255, -255, p_alphaTolerance));

    // overlay the second image:
    mat = p_clip2.transform.concatenatedMatrix;
    mat.tx -= bounds.xMin;
    mat.ty -= bounds.yMin;
    img.draw(p_clip2,mat,new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 255, 255, 255, p_alphaTolerance),"difference");

    // find the intersection:
    var intersection:Rectangle = img.getColorBoundsRect(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFF00FFFF);

    // if there is no intersection, return null:
    if (intersection.width == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    // adjust the intersection to account for the bounds:   
    intersection.x += bounds.xMin;
    intersection.y += bounds.yMin;
    return intersection;
};
```

Hopefully that will get you started and save someone else the frustration I had trying to find a solution!